# Intel Smart Response Technology (SSD Caching): Exclude partition?

Tags: ssd

Is there any way to exclude a partition from being cached when using Intel Smart Response Technology (SSD caching)?

I would like to build a machine that has a large RAID partition for long term file storage while maximizing performance of other uses (database server, application development).

I would like all the files on the RAID partition to bypass the SSD cache.

Is this possible?

EDIT: I'm using an ASUS Z87 motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your OS Installed, you would need to install the appropriate drivers and Intel's Rapid Storage Technology. You would then be able to tell which drives you wanted to cache. I have a development machine that has a RAID10 of platter drives that are for large file storage and a RAID0 platters which have just my OS and programs on it. I set (up to 64GB) on the RAID0 for the SSD Caching. Your motherboard also must support this; a few chipsets being the Z68 and Z77.

Comment: So it is configured at the drive level as opposed to the partition level?  Can you configure it to cache any subset of drives?